# Argparse how to change the default help (usage) section

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have the following Argument Parser configuration, through which I have defined the '--config' argument:

```
# Initialize the Argument Parser
clArgsParser = argparse.ArgumentParser (
    description = __program__.description,
    epilog = __program__.epilog,
    formatter_class = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
)

# Define '--config' argument
clArgsParser.add_argument (
    '-c', '--config',
    help = "Path to the Program's Configuration file.",
    type = str,
    action = 'store',
    dest = 'programConfigPath'              # Store the argument value into the variable 'programConfigPath'
)
```

Once the program with this code is executed and I type `--help` in the CL-Interface the following usage text is printed out for the '--config' argument:

```
optional arguments:
    -c PROGRAMCONFIGPATH, --config PROGRAMCONFIGPATH
```

However, I do NOT want the `PROGRAMCONFIGPATH` to be printed out, but instead I want  `<PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>` to be printed out.
So summarized:

```
Now:        -c PROGRAMCONFIGPATH,     --config PROGRAMCONFIGPATH
Shall be:   -c <PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>, --config <PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>
```

How can I do that without changing the name of the variable in which the CL-Argument parameter is stored: `dest = 'programConfigPath'`

Answer (score 0):

When ArgumentParser generates help messages, it needs some way to refer to each expected argument. An alternative name to the expected argument can be specified with [metavar](https://%20https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#metavar) option which will overwrite the default expected argument in the help message.

For example to change `PROGRAMCONFIGPATH` to `<PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>`, the following option has to be added to the `ArgumentParser`

```
metavar='<PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>'
```

This code:

```
# Define '--config' argument
clArgsParser.add_argument (
    '-c', '--config',
    help = "Path to the Program's Configuration file in the JSON format (e.g. 'ProgramConfig.json').",
    type = str,
    action = 'store',
    dest = 'programConfigPath',          # Store the argument value into the variable 'programConfigPath'
    metavar='<PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>'      # Specify alternative name in the helper (usage) section
)
```

will produce the following output:

```
options:
  -c <PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>, --config <PROGRAM_CONFIG_PATH>
```

Note that `metavar` only changes the displayed name - the name of the attribute on the `parse_args()` object is still determined by the `dest` value, in our case `dest = 'programConfigPath'`

Comment: The `<>` in this metavar might cause problems.  The usage formatter is brittle and has, in the past, had problems with special characters.  I don't remember how well that's been patched.

Comment: It works flawelessly with `argparse` v1.1 on my computer.